# How to display image in Facebook Sharer?

Tags: php, html, facebook

I'm using the code to display pop-up Facebook Sharer, but the glitch is, the image is not displaying.

```
<?php
    $title="My Wedding Lookbook! | BridalBook.ph 3rd Anniversary Promo";
    $url="http://www.bridalbook.ph/promos/bridalbook-3rd-year-anniv-promo/?preview=1";
    $summary="I just created my dream wedding lookbook! Getting married? Make your own on BridalBook.ph!";
    $image="http://pagsanjanpalmresort.com/moodboards/111.jpg";
?>

<a onClick="window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&amp;p[title]=<?php echo $title;?>&amp;p[summary]=<?php echo $summary;?>&amp;p[url]=<?php echo $url; ?>&amp;&p[images][0]=<?php echo $image;?>', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=548,height=325');"> 
Share on Facebook. 
</a>
```

What's gone wrong?

Comment: Some people suggest that sharer is deprecated. See second answer in [How to use Facebook Sharer in PHP](https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?s=100&[images][0]=http://pagsanjanpalmresort.com/moodboards/111.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

All the other parameters except for image url and Share url need to urlencoded.

Sample Javascript implementation follows

```
    imageUrl = 'http://pagsanjanpalmresort.com/moodboards/111.jpg';
    shareTitle = 'My%20Wedding%20Lookbook!%20%7C%20BridalBook.ph%203rd%20Anniversary%20Promo';
    desc = 'I%20just%20created%20my%20dream%20wedding%20lookbook!%20Getting%20married%3F%20Make%20your%20own%20on%20BridalBook.ph!';
    url = 'http://www.bridalbook.ph/promos/bridalbook-3rd-year-anniv-promo/?preview=1';

    window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=' + shareTitle + '&p[summary]=' + desc + '&p[url]=' + url + '&p[images][0]=' + imageUrl + '', 'sharer', 'toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
```

Comment: I think the image you are using is too big. Use this http://media.vedi-express.eu/62-788-large/rollup-sample-85-x-200-deluxe.jpg and see it work!!

Comment: I don't know if its the image size, I have tried to compressed the image, but it wasn't working...

Comment: here is my workaround, I upload the image in Google Photos and call the image location, and it works. I don't know what is the problem... but I let it the way it is for now... thank you all! :)

Comment: with size i meant dimensions @iamnards :) not file size.

Comment: yes @Jaspal Singh, i modify the dimension as well as size but it doesn't work

Comment: Ideal image dimensions are 320 by 320

Answer (score 0):

The [Open Graph meta tags](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/), specifically og:image, might help, depending on how you were wanting it to be displayed. Using the open graph tags, your website will appear as a link with a thumbnail. Clicking on the thumbnail will go to the url, not show the full photo within facebook.